# Проблема со сравнением одномерных масивов

Tags: c++

В общем, мне задали задание, у введённом двомерном массиве со "сторонами" N на N (n- вводит пользователь, также как и элементы массива) нужно найти количество элементов которые находятся выше дополнительной диагонали массива(это та что с верхнего правого угла в левый нижний) и равны элементам этой самой диагонали. То есть, например массив 4 на 4, диагональ равна 3 4 3 1 , элементы выше неё равны 3 4 6 3 5 3, и что бы в итоге вышло число 7 ( сначала проверяется первый элемент диагонали и сравнивается со всеми элементами выше диагонали, и так с каждым последующим элементом диагонали). То что в диагонали могут повторяться элементы не важно.
Я вот написал уже код , там всё работает за исключением как раз этого сравнения.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int i, j, f, g, b, n, k, v,x;
    const int MaxN = 100;
    x = 0;
    v = 0;
    k = 0;
    g = 0;
    cout << "Введіть кількість елементів в рядку і стовпцю квадратного масиву: ";
    cin >> n;
    float c;
    float diag[MaxN];
    float ver[MaxN];
    float arr[MaxN][MaxN];

    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++)
        {
            cout << "Введіть елемент массиву " << i + 1 << ", " << j + 1 << " =\t";
            cin >> arr[i][j];

        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Побічна діагональ матриці" << endl;
    for (i = 0, f = 0, j = n - 1; i <= n - 1; i++, f++, j--) {
        diag[f] = arr[i][j];
        cout << diag[f] << endl;

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Верхня частина матриці" << endl;
    for (j = 0, g = 1; j <= n - 1; j++, g++) {
        for (i = 0, b = 0; i < n - g; b++, i++) {
            v++;
            ver[b] = arr[i][j];
            cout << ver[b] << endl;
        }

    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // вот цикл со сравнением єлементов.
        for (j = 0; j <= v; j++) {
            if (diag[i] == ver[j]) {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Кількість однакових елементів з верхньої частини матриці і побічної матриці: " << k << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если что простите за мой плохой код и русский. И за украинский в коде.

Comment: а как из всего 6 элементов получается 7 равных элементам диагонали??

Comment: @Эникейщик Э.. если бы было шесть троек, и вся диагональ - тройки, то вообще было бы 24... Интересно, это условие неверно понято, или именно такое задано?

Comment: Да, но у меня это не работает так как нужно

Comment: Я могу если что скинуть в оригинале задание из документа

Comment: А покажите, просто интересно...

Comment: Задана квадратна матриця N*N . Серед елементів, які знаходяться вище побічної діагоналі, знайти кількість елементів, які співпадають з елементами побічної діагоналі.

Comment: Скажите, а вот тот пример, что Вы в вопросе приводите - это Вам преподаватель такой пример дал?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Странно... просто пример не соответствует вопросу. В вопросе речь идет о количестве элементов, совпадающих с побочной диагональю, а в примере - количество совпадений....

Comment: А это разве не одно и то же?

Comment: Нет :)  Количество элементов над  диагональю, совпадающих с элементами диагонали - 4 штуки, три тройки и одна четверка, то есть именно - сколько отдельных элементов. А количество совпадений - 7, как у Вас в примере. То есть то, сколько раз проверка на равенство дала истину. В первом случае наличие на диагонали повторяющихся элементов значения не имеет, во втором - имеет.

Comment: Хорошо, но как это оформить в коде?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123187/discussion-between---and-manukafool).